# Ubuntu 22.04 USB-C dock no video

Tags: ubuntu, usb, video, hdmi, dock-station

I've got a Wavlink WL-UMD502 usb-c docking station connected to a USB 3.2 Gen 2 port (USB-C) with an Ubuntu 22.04 5.15.0.56-generic kernel. I installed the device driver for the Wavlink docking station and followed the Readme.txt commands specific for Ubuntu which was:

```
sudo depmod -a
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Followed by a few reboots. Ethernet, Keyboard, and Mouse all go through the dock.

I also tried to load the kernel module generated by the Makefile for the WL-UMD502 driver by doing:

```
sudo modprobe rl8152.ko
```

with the following output from *sudo dmesg*

```
[ 4568.381336] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
```

I've also tried loading the *typec_displayport.ko* kernel module located in */lib/modules/5.15.0-56-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/typec/altmodes* but that's clearly for displayport support only.

That being said, I have a sneaking suspicion that the type-c port on my laptop only supports DisplayPort format and not HDMI which is what the docking station and external monitors are. Although I am curious if grabbing an older kernel module for type-c might work because some threads I've found seem to show working type-c video output for Ubuntu 20.04

I don't have an alternate mode HDMI to USB-C adapter at this time so I can't test the port itself.

Any thoughts? More information needed? A lot of people use Dell or HP docks lately. I haven't seen any questions related to Wavlink.

Comment: Thought it could be apparmor.service causing issues since I was seeing some apparmor="DENIED" but after disabling the service and rebooting nothing changed.

Comment: It used to work for me, but after the last few kernel updates on Linux Mint 21 (based on 22.04) it has stopped working. Still investigating. There has been posts on arch regarding a kernel version that had a bug in typec_displayport.

Comment: At this point I wouldn't doubt there being a bug. I've done more testing with two other docking stations from different manufacturers with no luck. `dmesg` isn't telling me much for errors trying to push video. All other usb modules load normally.